# Query Venue Tips at a greater Distance

Tags: foursquare

i want to query Venue Tips for specific keywords at a larger distance. currently when i do a query the distance is usually between 40-80 kilometers, however if i wanted to calculate a whole country I'd have to do multiple queries.

I've been singling out a particularly created by me in my hometown and adapting the lat and long coordinates, (+/- 40-80 Kilometers) it looks like the distance radius is not uniform, some kind of clusters fundamental to the foursquare data structure.

if i wanted to do a complete search for a country i'd have to define multiple points and hope that i include all of the desired area, also if the the resultset is larger than 500 i'd have to again divide the area to get results on a more granular basis.

my question basically is whether my approach is right or for anyone to provide additional hints

thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to search tips in that large of a area at the moment. That being said, the foursquare venue search behavior is constantly evolving so it's not inconceivable that a larger radius may someday be supported.

If you're building a user application, maybe you can show them a map and let them drag a pin around which then recenters where they're searching.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum supported radius is currently 100,000 meters. That's already a bit more than the 40-80 kilometers you mentioned.